# Unable to access SharePoint drive in Teams unless manually opened

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Problem: I'm currently working on some scripts that automates the whole teams-creation process. I can create teams with Graph API "Example: serviceClient.Teams.PostAsync(requestBody)". This automatically creates a team with the general channel.

Now I want to access the sharepoint drive behind it (would work like this: (await serviceClient.Teams[{TeamId}].Channels[{ChannelId}].GetAsync()).**FilesFolder **). This gets me the DriveItem of the Team (normally). Now I figured out, it only works if I go manually to the Team -> General -> Files. If I don't do this step, I get an error "Folder location for this channel is not ready yet, please try again later."

Steps to reproduce:

- Create team using Graph API
- Access the files folder of the general channel (general channel of the created team)

My question is: How can I programmatically access the SharePoint drive associated with a Teams channel without having to manually open it in Teams first? Is there any additional configuration or step that needs to be performed to ensure consistent access to the SharePoint drive through the API?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!